# How to show function arguments, or inline help in Spyder whilst using a non-spyder python interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, spyder

So for some initial context, I run a standalone version of Spyder 5, not downloaded through anaconda. I have recently been forced to create a virtual python environment through miniconda in order to update some python packages to the most recent versions as Spyder was using older versions like NumPy 1.24 and I need NumPy 1.26. This has meant that I am no longer using the in-built Spyder python interpreter, and it is now my virtual environment.

This has left me without some Spyder functionalities that I really enjoy, such as the inline pop-up that shows you possible continuations for your code including functions, or arguments of functions once you open a parenthesis.

I know you can go into preferences and create automatic connections for the editor and console to the help window, but this does not also bring back the inline pop-up. The only thing I've found to work so far, is to reset Spyder preferences to default, however this fix still doesn't work as I then have to change the python interpreter back to my conda environment and this causes the issue again.

An alternative help would be if anyone knows how to update the individual packages inbuilt to Spyder standalone without having to recreate a virtual environment through conda.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ask here : groups.google.com/g/spyderlib . I do get the nice stuff using a different interpreter the the one I run spyder into; did you check the Preferences/Plugins panel ?